# Is there a way to trigger a dynamic policy based on the number of connections?

Tags: amazon-web-services, autoscaling

I have an Auto Scaling Group where I want to set up a dynamic scaling policy based on the number of connections my servers are receiving.

These servers are all behind a Load Balancer, and I'd like to increase/decrease the number of servers based on the average number of connections.

I tried with the dynamic policy `Application Load Balancer request count per target` but my Load Balancer is a Network one, not an Application one, so I can not make it work. (But it would seem to be perfect).

How can I set up my Dynamic policy to trigger the up/down based on the number of connections?

Answer (score 1):

`RequestCountPerTarget` metric refers to the average number of HTTP request to a target. Since Network Load Balancers are layer 4 devices, they are not aware of HTTP/HTTPS or any other higher layer protocol. Obviously, they can route HTTP because HTTP runs over TCP, but they can not understand the HTTP protocol itself.

There is no similar metric to `RequestCountPerTarget` provided by the Network Load Balancer, as far as I'm aware of. What we can do to overcome this are the following:

1. Create a custom metric from our backend for every target, counting the number of HTTP requests. This metric can be [published to CloudWatch](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/monitoring/publishingMetrics.html) and can be used as input for auto scaling.
2. Publish a log entry for every request and [create a metric filter](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/logs/FilterAndPatternSyntax.html) from the logs. Although this would not require code change in the backend, having a lot of traffic could result a very noisy log streams and also could increase the costs significantly by ingesting a lot of leg entries in CloudWatch.

Comment: Thank you for the info, indeed, I agree with you on the TCP balancer vs HTTP. Right now, I send a "Count" event to Cloudwatch for every connections, but I've estimated my events to be about 250k per hour, so about 186M per month. This would cost about 186$ at Cloudwatch and I'd like to reduce this. Your second option is kind of like the same.

Comment: My current best bet would be to run a script every minute on the server, and count the number of open connections using netstat and send that number.